# Is the bus Turin → Verbania working in 2018?

Tags: public-transport, italy, tips-and-tricks, turin

This a bus that goes from Turin to the Maggiore Lake area every sunday during summer months. The information about the bus schedule on the official [bus company website](http://www.vcotrasporti.it/it/servizi_estivi.php) is from 2017.

I've seen that there is an e-mail address on the bus company website: prenotazioni@vcotrasporti.it. I've tried to write an e-mail to this address asking for  information. Unfortunately, this is the answer I've received:

> Your message to prenotazioni@vcotrasporti.it couldn't be delivered. 
>      prenotazioni wasn't found at vcotrasporti.it.

I've found another e-mail address on the bus company website, so I've tried to ask for information using this address, but I haven't received any anwser.

For these reasons I would like to ask: does anyone know if this bus line is working this summer?

Comment: If you can speak Italian, you should call il numero verde (free phone) 800 503001. Many Italian websites are notorious for not being updated. Trenitalia is always reliable though.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Yes, I speak Italian, but I immagine that this phone number is free if you call from an Italian phone number.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: OK, but I don't want to book right now. For the time being, I just only want to know if this bus exists so I can plan my trip.

Comment: Even if you call from a landline number in Spain, I don't imagine the cost will be that onerous. I think you have no choice but to call, in 2017 the bus service **had to be booked**, see:  "*È necessaria la prenotazione entro le ore 11 del giorno prima, chiamando il numero verde 800 503001 o lo 0323/518711.*" (You must book by 11.00 the day before, call freephone bla, bla...)

Comment: Thanks, @Mari-LouA, I know that: I understand Italian without any problem (except for some words and expressions I ask about at Italian.SE ;).

Comment: I have just received an answer to one of my e-mails saying that this service has been suppressed from this year.

Comment: Too many Italians have cars nowadays, a family of four will own four cars, it probably didn't make economic sense to maintain the service for the very few (mostly elderly) who cannot drive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I live in Italy, so I've just called the freephone number and the number is "non abilitata" which means it no longer works. I called the landline and the *new* number to call for public transport is 0323 518611.

Obviously, at this hour (currently it's 19.30 Italy time) their offices are closed.  But you can call Mondays to Saturdays from 05.00–19.00. Speak to the person in charge and they should be able to inform you if they still run the bus service from Turin to Verbania.

**UPDATE**
I just called the bus company (press 1 for timetable, costs, lost & found,  etc.) and unfortunately,  the service is no longer running. The OP will have to look elsewhere. I'm sorry.

I would email the hotel, or the airbnb etc. where you are staying and ask them if there are any buses running that will take you to your desired destination. Failing that, take the train. [Trenitalia.com](http://www.trenitalia.com/) is a fast and reliable website, and train tickets are very cheap in Italy compared to the UK.  You need to know the exact name of the stations though, it's not enough to write "Torino" and "Verbania"

I've done the search and this is the cost **for two people** travelling one way, departing August 5.

> [image]

Comment: I don't have a lineline, but I'll try to phone to this phone number from my mobile phone if I'm not able to find this information in any other way. My experience with this phone numbers, at least at my country, is that you have to spend a lot of time at phone, passing from one menu to another, and waiting and waiting... And sometimes you have to phone again.

Comment: @Charo any luck? If you did get lucky, you can post the VCO's reply in an answer and accept it yourself.

Comment: Of course, I'll do it. There are several e-mail addresses at the "Contatti" page, so I'm still trying. At present, I haven't received any anwser.

Comment: The phone is quicker.

Comment: @Charo tell me exactly where you want to take the bus from Torino. It doesn't cost me a penny to call from my landline.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Mari-LouA, but the problem is that we are going to stay at Torino and the train option maybe is too much time to go and come back the same day. With this bus you could go to Stresa in the morning, visit the Borromean islands and come back to Torino in the afternoon spending a reasonable amount of time travelling in the bus.